# What are the parental controls within Windows 8 and how do I use them?

Tags: windows-8, parental-controls

I've got some little ones that I want to be able to use my PC, BUT I don't want them using my account since it's an admin account.  I've created a user account for them without admin privileges and now I'm looking to see if there is a way to do the following:

- Prevent them from downloading/purchasing Metro apps
- Limit amount of time on Computer
- Limit time of day they can access
- Limit internet browsing based on age
- Prevent them from installing desktop applications
- Any other parental controls that I can set

I'm looking for a good exhaustive overview of the parental controls found within Windows 8 and a brief synopsis on how to use those tools.

Comment: Not going to post this as an answer, but here's what appears to be a pretty decent summary: http://howto.cnet.com/8301-11310_39-57533877-285/how-to-use-parental-controls-in-windows-8/

Comment: Yeah, too tired to copy-paste and re-word all this :), but take a look at [What's New in Windows 8 Family Safety](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/jj155495%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the [Set Up Parental Controls for Windows 8](http://www.groovypost.com/howto/windows-8-parental-controls/) tutorial.

Answer (score 2):

You would still use [Windows Family Safety](http://familysafety.live.com/) just like you may have done in Windows 7.

Features include:

1. Activity Report, which tells you what websites they try to go to,
   which apps they run, what times, etc.
2. Web Filtering
3. Contact Management
4. Time Limits - in 30 minute increments
5. Game Restrictions
6. App Restrictions
7. The restricted user can also make requests on a per app/game/website
       basis.
   [image]

Setting it up is fairly straightforward.  Once you create the account you want to monitor, you'll see a check box to turn on Family Safety.  Once its monitored, you just sign in to Windows Family Safety and manage settings from the website.
[image]

Comment: links are great... when they're used as reference.  I'm looking for a list of features and a quick guide to using these features.

Comment: @KronoS edited details on features

Answer (score 1):

Use a free app called Qustodio. I use it to monitor who my girl talks to on Facebook as the app allows me to watch the profile pictures of accounts she interacts with. My way of ensuring that she stays safe. Just Google for it.